# Probability of solution to the Gauss elimination method

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$ where $q$ is prime, finding a vector $s \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ such that $A^{T}s=0 \mod q$ can be done by the Gauss jordon elimination method.

Can we say if the matrix $A$ is uniformly chosen then, the vector $s$ is statistically close to uniform distribution?

Comment: You are missing some information here. How is $s$ related to $A$? And is $q$ a prime number, prime power, random integer,...?

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Consider $q=7,A=\begin{pmatrix}3&6&3\\2&5&2\end{pmatrix}$; the Gauss elimination of the equation $A[x,y,z]^T=0$ gives $x+z=0,y=0$, that is, $7$ solutions.

EDIT 1. the right question would concern the equation, in $s$, $As=b$ in the case $n=m$.

EDIT 2. Answer to Diger.

Let $A\in M_{n,m}(K)$ (where $K=\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$) be randomly (uniform law) chosen. We assume that $q$ (and eventually $n,m$) are large integers. Note that $s\in K^m$ and not $K^n$.

If $n\leq m$ (the case above), then $A$ is full rank ($n$) with probability $\approx 1$. Then $\ker(A)$ has dimension $m-n$ and $As=0$ has $q^{m-n}$ solutions.

If $m\leq n$, then $A$ is full rank $(m)$ with probability $\approx 1$. Then $A$ is one to one and $s=0$ is the sole solution.

Comment: Is this matrix uniformly chosen?

Comment: If a matrix $A$ is uniformly chosen can we say anything about the probability distribution of vector $s$ which is the solution to the equation $A^Ts=0 \mod q$

Comment: $s$ is not a vector; $s$ is a vector space. OK, I spend my time...